# In JBoss 7.1.1, how can I make my WAR dependent on my EAR

Tags: jboss, dependencies

I'm migrating my 4.2.2 JBoss app to 7.1.1. I have most of it working, but I occasionally get an error when my WAR file loads prior to an EAR file that it uses for database access.

I am currently delaying the load of the WAR by placing it in a sub-directory of the deployments directory, but this seems like such a kludge.

I have tried putting the EAR file in as a module and them making the WAR depend on it through the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file placed in the war. This seems to load fine, but then the database access isn't getting pushed through.

I have tried adding the ear to the dependencies tag in the WAR's manifest, but doesn't work either.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Use `<initialize-in-order>true</initialize-in-order>`

In application.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  version="6" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd">

  <application-name>sampleapp</application-name>
  <initialize-in-order>true</initialize-in-order>
  <module>
    <ejb>some-ejb.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>some-web-app.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>test</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

Then the oerder you have specified in application.xml will be honored.

Also [available through maven ear plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/generate-application-xml-mojo.html#initializeInOrder).

Comment: That doesn't work when the war is deployed outside of the ear file.

Comment: @JosephNelson true. if you're actually deploying it outside the .ear file, you have to add a considerably more detail to your question for it to be answerable... what modules you have in the .ear then? how is it actually doing the database access? how have you tried to export it? what's the mechanism that isn't getting pushed through?

Comment: a natural way in the EE world would be to export data source providing classes EJBs and have the dependendency lookup through JNDI